# Limit Oracle / ASPX Query Time

Tags: asp.net, database, oracle

How can I automatically kill a query that runs for more than 60 seconds?

The queries are called from a VB ASPX page to an Oracle database.

I don't mind putting the limit in the database itself or in the calling aspx code.

FYI: I use a `asp:GridView` bound to a 'asp:SqlDataSource` for querying the database.

FYI: A `connectionString` for `System.Data.OracleClient` does not have a `Connection Timeout` property ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracleconnection.connectionstring.aspx))

Comment: Won't let me change it now.  All I can do is wait for an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the database, you can create a [PROFILE](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6010.htm#i2065930) for a user which will terminate a statement (or session) if it exceeds certain limits. However these are measured in LOGICAL_READS_PER_CALL or CPU_PER_CALL rather than time. Also, bear in mind that for INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE/MERGE, the termination will require any changes done to be rolled back, which can take additional time.

Comment: Just to clarify, CPU_PER_CALL is time, but purely CPU time not end-user time.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `CommandTimeout` property on the command object in your vb.net code.

Comment: In that case, you can set a timeout for the connection in the connection string.